# Tailwind css background gradient not applying

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

My tailwind background gradient is not being applied

here is my html code:

```
<div>
   <button className="bg-gradient-to-r from-primary-orange via-secondary-orange to-lighter-orange w-4/5 p-4 mt-10 rounded">Search Flights</button>
</div>
```

My tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    backgroundColor: theme => ({
      ...theme('colors'),
      'primary-orange': '#FF8C00',
      'secondary-orange':'#FFA500',
      'lighter-orange':'#FFD700'
     })
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Running my react script with post-css so all the other colors I add to tailwind.config are working once I generate the post-css just not the gradient.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I had faced this issue, I checked all the config and module files, and finally, I solved that by disabling the 'dark reader' Chrome extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `extend` section of your `tailwind.config.js` file  if you'd like to extend the default color palette rather than override it. Then add `gradientColorStops` attribute to it where you can write your custom colors.

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [],
    darkMode: false, 
    theme: {
        extend: {
            gradientColorStops: theme => ({
                'primary': '#FF8C00',
                'secondary': '#FFA500',
                'danger': '#FFD700',
            }),
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```